# How to set up an intent-filter to SEND action only when sending contact?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I wanted to register an intent-filter on my app so I can share a contact from other application to mine.

I can already achieve this by adding this to my manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

The problem is that my application appears in all "Share" or "Send to" popups from other applications sharing text data. How can I limit this so my app only appears on the contact share popup?

I already tried to use `android:host="com.android.contacts"` inside `<data>` but didn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a `android:host` you also need to set an `android:scheme` otherwise it is ignored. Try setting it to be `android:scheme="content"`. All this will do though is prevent you from accepting intents without a data URI that contain the authority "com.android.contacts".

That being said, the mime-type you have specified will accept any text based content. Is that what you intended? Maybe you should be using the [contact item mime-type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) specified by Google.

Comment: Oh, now I got it! Using just `android:mimeType="text/x-vcard"` solved my problem! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @RicardoOtero  i was finding same. it saved my time thanks.